# POST form data includes GET parameters used to generate the form

Tags: java, html, spring, forms, http

This one blew my mind for a while and now I think I know what it is.

I have this basic form that uses POST to submit the values.

```
<form action="./change" method="post">
    <p class="fieldName">Username (your email address):</p>
    <input type="text" name="thetaname"/>
    <p class="fieldName">Password:</p>
    <input type="password" name="thetaword"/>
    <p class="fieldName">Confirm Password:</p>
    <input type="password" name="confirm"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="authkey" value="djj"/>
    <p class="errorMsg"></p>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

and it submits to the same location that originally created the form. The issue seems to be that the form is originally created with a GET parameter on the URL and the form is a POST. When I look at the log, it looks like the GET parameter is included on the post and my Spring app is getting confused.

I'm using GET for the original because I'm emailing the link to the user. I'm using POST on the submit because I want to make sure the passwords and stuff are encrypted.

I'm running NGINX in front of Spring boot and it's returning an empty string from the submit.

The GET is listed as GET only on my method and POST as POST only on my method in my controller.

Ideas?

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a work-around if not an answer. I simply renamed the second change to change2 and posted to change2. This seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I cant say i completely understand your question but this might help;

If your using Java as your server side technology then please change the action attribute to (action="change") not (action="./change").

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your controller is within a Servlet container. In that case Servlet will combine both url query parameters and POST parameters together. You can always get all of them via `getParameterValues`. See also this post: 
[How do I separate out query string params from POST data in a java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459441/how-do-i-separate-out-query-string-params-from-post-data-in-a-java-servlet)

Comment: He said Spring Boot, SO he's using Spring REST to write his controller, he's not using a SErvlet.